# Scala map method on option

Tags: scala

I am new to scala, please help me with the below question.

Can we call map method on an Option? **(e.g. Option[Int].map()?)**.

If yes then could you help me with an example?

Comment: Yes... lets say you created an `Option[Int]` as `val intOpt  = Some(1)`. Now you want to transform it into `Option[String]`, you can do  `val strOpt = intOpt.map( i => i.toString)`

Comment: And next time, please try to put some effort to do the learning before asking a question on StackOverFlow.

Comment: thanks for your reply..As i am new i am little confused with option keyword.however ill put some efforts on it..

Comment: If you're not familiar with the scaladoc, you should be. The page for `Option` even has examples using `map`. As @SarveshKumarSingh says,  a little research is expected before asking questions. http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.8/#scala.Option

Answer (score 15):

Here's a simple example:

```
val x = Option(5)

val y = x.map(_ + 10)

println(y)
```

This will result in `Some(15)`.
If `x` were `None` instead, `y` would also be `None`.

Answer (score 11):

Yes:

```
  val someInt = Some (2)
  val noneInt:Option[Int] = None
  val someIntRes = someInt.map (_ * 2) //Some (4)
  val noneIntRes = noneInt.map (_ * 2) //None
```

See [docs](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.Option)

You can view an option as a collection that contains exactly 0 or 1 items. Mapp over the collection gives you a container with the same number of items, with the result of applying the mapping function to every item in the original.

Comment: "You can view an option as a collection that contains exactly 0 or 1 items" - this was really helpful!

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes it's more convenient to use `fold` instead of mapping `Option`s. Consider the example:

```
scala> def printSome(some: Option[String]) = some.fold(println("Nothing provided"))(println)
printSome: (some: Option[String])Unit

scala> printSome(Some("Hi there!"))
Hi there!

scala> printSome(None)
Nothing provided
```

You can easily proceed with the real value inside `fold`, e.g. map it or do whatever you want, and you're safe with the default fold option which is triggered on `Option#isEmpty`.