# Broadcasting of scala options on sub-elements

Tags: scala, optional-parameters

I want to work with options in scala and broadcast this functionality in properties of case class.
My question is: if an instance of the object is optional, [code below] and I want to have these properties as optional without using the Option/Some keywords How can I do This?

here is some example:

```
case class T(a: String, b: Int)
case class E(t: Option[T], c: String)

val myTObj = E(t = Some(T("foo", "bar")), c="foo")
```

I want `myTobj.t.a.getOrElse("")` and not `Option(myTobj.t.get).getOrElse("")`is it possible?

Comment: I won't write the answer here, just to give you the idea, see what the `map` method of `Option` does.

Comment: `myTObj.t.flatMap(_.a).getOrElse("")`

Comment: `myTObj.t.map(_.a).getOrElse("")`. Pretty sure there is no use for `flatMap` here. It's essentially the same as described [in the accepted answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38866821/2707792).